# foreach Loop that output JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

Hey I'm a trainee and I have a problem.
Im trying to make an Calender web-program with JavaScript.

So i have an JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
   "datei1":{
      "titel":"text",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-20 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-20 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort : text."

},
   "datei2":{
      "titel":"TEST",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-03 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-04 00:00:00",
      "text":"wedwefwfacafwaq"

},
   "datei3":{
      "titel":"Jahresmeeting 2019",
      "datumbegin":"2020-01-06 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-01-06 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort : test text : 10 Uhr "

},
   "datei4":{
      "titel":"Admin Meeting zum Update 0.5.5",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-27 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-27 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort : probeeeeeeeeeeeee"

},
   "datei5":{
      "titel":"Schulung zum Thema Datenschutz",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-19 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-19 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort : text text text"

},
   "datei6":{
      "titel":"Brandschutz Lehrgang",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-17 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-17 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort: text text test text"

},
   "datei7":{
      "titel":"Bereich Wechsel 2020 Mai",
      "datumbegin":"2020-05-14 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-09-19 00:00:00",
      "text":"Bereich 5 wird zu Bereich 3 gewechselt."

},
   "datei8":{
      "titel":"TEST",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-06 12:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-06 15:00:00",
      "text":"sdasasfdsdafsafsfsfswf"

}
}
```

so and now im trying to read out every "datei" property.

my JavaScript Code looks like that at the moment:

```
function GetData(xxx)
{


  var test = document.getElementById("table_data").innerHTML;

  var testJson = JSON.parse(test);

  console.log(testJson.datei1.titel);
  console.log(testJson.datei1);
  console.log(testJson);
  var keyCount  = Object.keys(testJson).length;
  console.log(keyCount);

  var datei_anzahl = 1;

    var titel = testJson.datei1.titel;
    var start_jahr = testJson.datei1.datumbegin;
    var end_jahr = testJson.datei1.datumend;
    var text = testJson.datei1.text;

    xxx.push({ title: titel, start: new Date(start_jahr), end: new Date(end_jahr), allDay: true, text: text  });

  return xxx;
}

var data = [];
data = GetData(data);
```

so I only have now all properties of "datei1"
But I want that an **foreach** loop go threw every "datei".
So in the first round it gets everything of datei1, in the second round it gets everyrhing of datei2 and so on.

Can you please help I'm stuck at this problem for 3hours.

Comment: You could e.g. use `Object.keys(json)` to get the keys of the object in an array. Then you can loop through that array.

Comment: "datei1", "datei2", ... why aint't this an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
for(var date in testJson) {
    var titel = testJson[date].titel;
    var start_jahr = testJson[date].datumbegin;
    var end_jahr = testJson[date].datumend;
    var text = testJson[date].text;

    xxx.push({ title: titel, start: new Date(start_jahr), end: new Date(end_jahr), allDay: true, text: text  });
}

return xxx;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key){
    var title = json[key].titel;
  var datumbegin = json[key].datumbegin
  console.log(title, datumbegin)
})
```

Try this. Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbke43to/

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```js
function GetData(xxx) {
  
  var jsonData = document.getElementById("table_data").innerHTML; 
  jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
 
  let keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
 for(const k of keys){
  xxx.push(jsonData[k]); 
 }  
  return xxx;
}

var data = [];
data = GetData(data);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<textarea id="table_data">{
   "datei1":{
      "titel":"text",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-20 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-20 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort : text text text."

},
   "datei2":{
      "titel":"TEST",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-03 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-04 00:00:00",
      "text":"wedwefwfacafwaq"

},
   "datei3":{
      "titel":"Jahresmeeting 2019",
      "datumbegin":"2020-01-06 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-01-06 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort : text test text"

},
   "datei4":{
      "titel":"Admin Meeting zum Update 0.5.5",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-27 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-27 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort :text text test text"

},
   "datei5":{
      "titel":"Schulung zum Thema Datenschutz",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-19 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-19 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort : text test ext ext

},
   "datei6":{
      "titel":"Brandschutz Lehrgang",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-17 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-17 00:00:00",
      "text":"Ort: text text textr"

},
   "datei7":{
      "titel":"Bereich Wechsel 2020 Mai",
      "datumbegin":"2020-05-14 00:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-09-19 00:00:00",
      "text":"Bereich 5 wird zu Bereich 3 gewechselt."

},
   "datei8":{
      "titel":"TEST",
      "datumbegin":"2020-02-06 12:00:00",
      "datumend":"2020-02-06 15:00:00",
      "text":"sdasasfdsdafsafsfsfswf"

}
}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your json file to array json file

```
[{ datei : '...'} , { datei2 : '...'}]
```

its will be array and you can use foreach loop something like this to read data per loop

If you cant change json file, use this for convert to array first before do loop.

```js
    const testJson = {
       "datei1":{
          "titel":"text",
          "datumbegin":"2020-02-20 00:00:00",
          "datumend":"2020-02-20 00:00:00",
          "text":"Ort : text."

    },
       "datei2":{
          "titel":"TEST",
          "datumbegin":"2020-02-03 00:00:00",
          "datumend":"2020-02-04 00:00:00",
          "text":"wedwefwfacafwaq"

    },
       "datei3":{
          "titel":"Jahresmeeting 2019",
          "datumbegin":"2020-01-06 00:00:00",
          "datumend":"2020-01-06 00:00:00",
          "text":"Ort : test text : 10 Uhr "

    },
       "datei4":{
          "titel":"Admin Meeting zum Update 0.5.5",
          "datumbegin":"2020-02-27 00:00:00",
          "datumend":"2020-02-27 00:00:00",
          "text":"Ort : probeeeeeeeeeeeee"

    },
       "datei5":{
          "titel":"Schulung zum Thema Datenschutz",
          "datumbegin":"2020-02-19 00:00:00",
          "datumend":"2020-02-19 00:00:00",
          "text":"Ort : text text text"

    },
       "datei6":{
          "titel":"Brandschutz Lehrgang",
          "datumbegin":"2020-02-17 00:00:00",
          "datumend":"2020-02-17 00:00:00",
          "text":"Ort: text text test text"

    },
       "datei7":{
          "titel":"Bereich Wechsel 2020 Mai",
          "datumbegin":"2020-05-14 00:00:00",
          "datumend":"2020-09-19 00:00:00",
          "text":"Bereich 5 wird zu Bereich 3 gewechselt."

    },
       "datei8":{
          "titel":"TEST",
          "datumbegin":"2020-02-06 12:00:00",
          "datumend":"2020-02-06 15:00:00",
          "text":"sdasasfdsdafsafsfsfswf"

    }
    };

    // convert to array 
    let data = [];
    for (let key in testJson) {
      if (testJson.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        data.push({name : key , data : testJson[key]})
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

then you just

```
data.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

happy coding